# How To Bind Month Name In Analysis Services 2008

Tags: service, analysis

I Have One Time_Table Which include following columns.
      id int (identity),
      date datetime,
      month Int,
      Quarter int ,
      Year  int

in Analysis services - How Can we Bind Month Columnn To Month Name In Cube .
Actually , I Want Month Name Should Be Dispaly instead of Month Number (I Have Month Number In My Time Table and There Is Not Jan , Feb But I Want To Dispaly Jan, Feb.. Instead Of 1,2 ...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column with the Month Name in your table Time_Table and use it as the NameColumn for your Month attribute.

Same thing for quarter and year, you need columns with the labels that you want to see.